# P2P file sharing application

Tags: java, p2p

I have developed a simple file sharing application in java using TCP socket. Now, the question is how do i make this application P2P? Can Distributed Hash Table (DHT) do that or there are other options that i can implement in my application to make it P2P? I have been trying to get ideas on this for a long time but i only get more confused. Please help.

Comment: Could you please describe more the part that you already implemented, so we can explain better what is missing?

Comment: I have created a Client and a Server using TCP socket.However, i have coded both client and server in one single application. Right now what my application can do is connect to a server, search for files in a folder (my app creates a folder where clients can look for files they want) and if any match is found, the file is transferred to the client. Right now the nature of my application is basically client/server and i have no clue on how to make it P2P. So, my question is can DHT make my application P2P or there are other measures that i can implement? 
Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Also, look into JXTA, also written in Java - loads of material about that on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The [Forest platform](https://github.com/le-moulin-studio/forest) which is in early development is targeting applications like your. You might want to take a look at it.

The only problem is that it is still in development and is not yet usable. I advise you to keep an eye on it and try to use it once it reaches it first release.

**EDIT to answer the comment under your question:**

Your application would need to connect the some peers. Depending on how you choose them (random people or know contacts), you are using respectively a peer-to-peer ('p2p') network or a friend-to-friend ('f2f') network.

Forest is providing applications a f2f network, but application are free to route messages on the top of this network to achieve (anonymous) p2p.

For a classical p2p network, you would need to connect a DHT, and you would need to bootstrap to it via a (or some) server(s) which take part in the DHT.

In general, p2p application are not so simple to do, and you will need to deal with a lot more details here and there. If you really want to experiment with them, you can go to check existing DHT libraries and see how they work. You might first want to go to read the article on [Wikipedia about Kademlia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) which is the base for the most used DHT algorithms.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely keep an eye on it.

Comment: how to use Forest Platform ?
is there any Template code or Documentation of it ?

Comment: The Forest platform is a dead project (was made by me). Forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your description it sounds like you have already created a simplistic P2P application.  If you are looking for the next step I would setup a DHT server ([bamboo](http://bamboo-dht.org/)). Next, modify your original application to get a list of available files from the DHT instead of connecting directly to the other peers for file lists.

Answer (score 0):

I  develop a simple P2P file sharing application in java too,but i find it hard . If you write it in java . You can search for Vuze or jBittorrent , which may help you develop it faster.